# How to connect MPLAB X with mikroICD?

Tags: microchip, mplab

How can I connect the MPLAB X software from MicroChip with the mikroICD debugger on my Big Pic 5 board of microElektronics so I can flash and debug my assembler programs? The MPLAB X Software only contains 'ICD 2' and 'ICD 3' under the menu 'Programmers'.. I want to type in a program in assembler in MPLAB X and then be able to set breakpoints and check the registers while it is paused on my Big Pic 5 board.

Comment: Ask the mikroICD manufacturer, obviously.  That failing, you could (gasp!) read the manual.  In any case, this is not a electronics question and is therefore off topic here.

Comment: Thanks anyway. (By the way this question was suggested here by someone of Superuser)
proof: http://superuser.com/questions/371103/how-to-connect-mplab-with-mikroicd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly (and [manual](http://www.mikroe.com/esupport/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=3&nav=0) seems to agree with me), mikroICD only supports mikroElektronika's development tools and searches aren't bringing any hacks. Since mikroE is playing the vendor lock-in card, you seem to be out of luck (although some sources claim that it's Microchip that's blocking the compatibility part). If the board has programing connector (I can't check right now), you could use a Pickit with it.

You could also try asking mikroE's support for any tips on assembly debugging. Some of their software my support it, but I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere in official documentation.

Comment: Using a Pickit seems the best answer...